# How To Hide New Item from Ribbon Classic SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, site-level-ribbon, new-item

How to hide New Item menu from classic SharePoint Online Ribbon UI?

[image]

I am already using Toolbar Type with "No Toolbar". But I want to hide "New Item" button from Ribbon.

Please advice. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS below to script editor web part:

```
<style>
    span[id='Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem-Large'] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. this is working for me!

Comment: I'm glad to help you. You can mark this post as answer. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the script editor webpart on the page and add the below code to it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem-Large");
elem.style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your response. i am already put your code in script editor. But 'new item' cannot hide. Please guide me

Comment: I am using script editor in list/windows load

Answer (score 0):

Try using below CSS to hide the "New Item" button from your page:

```
#Ribbon\.ListItem\.New\.NewListItem-Large {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Try this and let me know if this works for you.